# Hourly hotels/capsules near Haneda Airport that allow late morning stays?

Tags: japan, accommodation, tokyo, sleeping, hnd

I will soon have the dubious pleasure of landing in HND at **5 AM**, after an overnight flight that I know from experience won't let me get much sleep. I have a hotel for the night, but check-in time isn't until 3 PM and I can't count on getting a 6/7 AM early checkin.

So **I would like to crash in a capsule, cheap business hotel** or equivalent, ideally **until noon** or so. The only problem is, virtually all hotels in Japan have a **checkout time of 10 AM sharp**, with extensions either impossible or very expensive. <s>This includes</s> the only capsule hotel actually in Haneda, [First Cabin](https://first-cabin.jp/en/), which has both hourly rates and a 3-hour morning package, both ending at 10 AM. **Update**: They're actually open and accept guests 24/7! The only catch is that they close the showers for cleaning for a few hours at 10 AM.

Any ideas? I'm open to anything between Haneda and a train/monorail line to the city core as well (Kamata, Shinagawa, Hamamatsucho, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, turns out I was misreading their website: First Cabin *is* open to hourly stays 24/7, the only catch being that they close the showers for a few hours from 10 AM.

I tried them out this morning (I'm actually typing this inside the capsule!): the morning package is a minimum of 3 hours for ¥3000 in a "First Class Cabin", with additional hours ¥1000 each.   So my 5-hour stay from 6 to 11 AM cost me ¥5000.

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily what you are looking for, but you could book an extra night at the hotel prior to the night when you do have a booking and tell them that you have a really late checkin at 7AM and don't give your room away.

This has the advantage that you can go directly to your main hotel and crash there rather than dealing with going to/from a second hotel.

However I have no idea if it is financially better/worse for you to do this.

Comment: It's a possibility, but paying a full night's cost to stay a few hours seems a bit inefficient.  I travel light, so switching hotels is not much a problem.

Comment: @jpatokal If your desired accommodation type doesn't exist, then a comparison of efficiencies is kind of moot.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly valid, I'm just pretty sure there are cheaper options out there.  Tokyo is full of hotels that charge by the hour, surely they can't *all* kick out their guests at 10 AM sharp?

Answer (score 1):

There are many *"Internet-cafe"* in the center of Tokyo and they sell its seats in more flexible time slot, usually starting by 3 hours. They don't sell the seats like the typical accommodations such as hotels and hostels, so you can purchase whatever hours you like just on arrival.

These cafes were originally designed for the use of a computer and Internet with drink, but now is used as a cheap accommodation mainly for people from the countryside who usually have unstable, irregular jobs in Tokyo and can't afford to the rent. That makes many Internet cafes adopt services such as shower rooms, tooth brushes, hair dryers, etc...

But the quality as the accommodation is, IMHO, quite awful. If you are extremely sleepy I think you have no problem on sleeping there, but I rather want to spend some time in (normal) cafes.

If you want to lie asleep, choose a *"couple seat"* which is more spacious.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a bed, I can't sleep in a seat.  (Which is also the reason I can't sleep on the flight...)